# How do I access authorized user properties in the WebSphere application Lawson?

Tags: websphere

I'm assisting another developer with adding a link to a page in a product called Lawson that we use in-house. I need to pass the authenticated user's employee ID to an HTML page we're bolting on. I'm still looking at existing pages on the server, but thought I'd ask: does anyone know how the Javascript object that represents the authenticated user works? It looks like something server-side must be dynamically creating a Javascript object that has useful properties. It is usually called 'AuthUser'. I want to add the necessary JS references to my new page to support this object and access its properties. Does anyone have any experience with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a portal session, you can access this in javascript through attributes of portalWnd.oUserProfile:

```
alert(portalWnd.oUserProfile.getAttribute("id"))
```

This will give you the logged in user's short username.  Many other attributes are available.  To see a complete list, log into a portal session and then replace the URL with:

```
http://YOURPORTALSERVER/servlet/Profile
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "bolting on", but if you want to pass an attribute to an external page launched from a Portal session, you could create a user shortcut via Portal preferences using something like:

```
javascript:window.open("http://yourserver/yourpage.html?user=" + portalWnd.oUserProfile.getAttribute("id"))
```

as the target and process in yourpage.html like a normal GET method form.

If you are still puzzling over this all these months later, provide some specifics if you need more guidance.